# Error when loading .xib into a UIView

Tags: swift, uiview

I am having issues trying to load my .xib into a UIView. I have created a xib file and subclassed UIView as the same name. I have changed the class of the xib file to the ProfileBarView class.  In my UIView code I have:

```
import UIKit
import EDStarRating

class ProfileBarView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var studentNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var universityNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var starRatingView: EDStarRating!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ProfileBarView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(self.view)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ProfileBarView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(self.view)

    }


}
```

However I am getting the error:  `Value of type ProfileBarView has no member 'view.` What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: A `UIView` object has no property `view`. How can you do `self.view` then? `self.addSubiew(NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ProfileBarView", owner: self, options: nil)[0])`?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job.

```
  override init(frame: CGRect) {


        super.init(frame: frame)
        let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ProfileBarView", owner: self, options: nil)[0]
        addSubview(view as! UIView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ProfileBarView", owner: self, options: nil)[0]
        addSubview(view as! UIView)
    }
```